# php - Cookie value gets changed to different value

Tags: php, cookies

I set my cookie with PHP like this:

```
setcookie(
"hero",
", Comma . Dot < Left > Right - Dash _Underline / Slash \\ Backslash",
time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

But somehow, this is the value of the cookie:

> %2C+Comma+.+Dot+%3C+Left+%3E+Right+-+_Underline+%2F+Slash+Backslash

And not:

> , Comma . Dot < Left > Right - Dash _Underline / Slash \ Backslash

---

Strangely, I tried to get the cookie value like this:

```
echo $_COOKIE["hero"];
```

And that resulted in:

> , Comma . Dot < Left > Right - Dash _Underline / Slash \ Backslash

Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP automatically url encodes the value portion of a cookie when it is set.

Read the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.setcookie.php) entry on `setcookie();`

Comment: So PHP will decode the value portion of a cookie when getting its value?

Comment: Yes. If you want to set the cookie without encoding, use `setrawcookie`.

Comment: There's some discussion of this matter here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do I get a cookie value without decoding its value?

Comment: PHP automatically decodes it. You can yourself (the user) find the encoded version, the same way you found it earlier, because if you weren't able to find the encoded version earlier you wouldn't have asked this question. But I'm pretty sure you can't do it with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can set raw cookie then value will remain unchanged, Then value will not be automatically urlencoded when sent to the browser. for more info

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php